# How to write a Config App for a Console App - sharing data?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, configuration, settings

My console app uses a bunch of string variables entered by the user. Currently the user can type these as parameters to the console app which then persists them using `Properties.Settings`.

Instead I'd like a GUI app which has a bunch of text boxes and a 'Save' button.

How can I make this work? I presume there needs to be a way for each app to read/save the common variables. It should work without needing admin privileges when installed on customer's machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET supports XML (De)Serialization.

Define a class with your setting parameters as fields, connect those fields to your `GUI` elements, the way you want. Write that class to the XML file and restore the values on application launch.

Comment: Will this work when the app is installed into the Program Files directory without admin privileges?

Comment: There is no way to modify files stored in write-protected places without user confirmation or privilege escalation, so you can't update your settings file stored in `ProgramsFiles` directory unless you choose another path to save the settings file (ex. Application Data folder).

Comment: Exactly - the built in Properties.Settings stores data in the Application Data folder. Is it possible for both apps to share the same file when using the Application Settings feature built into VS?

Comment: You can actually share settings between projects. take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555396/en-us. If I were you, I would use a *shared* `DLL` with it's own application settings and reference it in both Console and GUI applications so they will use the same settings file through that shared `DLL`.

Comment: Thanks that might work. So either than or XML (De)Serialization